# EPPLUS preserve date format when saving CSV

Tags: c#, epplus

I am using EPPLUS to create a csv file.  When I create an Excel file, I can format the date thus:

```
ws.Cells["A:A"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-MMM-dd";
```

Which is what I need in my csv.  However, if I try to save the worksheet as a csv, any dates end up as numbers.

***EDIT - I appreciate Excel stores the date as a serial number, I was just wondering if EPPLUS had a feature I can't locate to help me out.

Comment: That's because Excel stores dates as a number (number of days since 31st December 1899) and only uses formatting to show you that number as a date. When saving to a CSV (even from Excel) dates will be exported as the serial number. You will have to convert the number to a string (without formatting) if you want to preserve the formatting when exporting as CSV

Comment: @phuzi - yes, I appreciate that, I just wondered if EPPLUS had a feature I can't find that helped me out.  Thanks for your response though, I have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are setting the value to a proper `DateTime` value in code, you should be able to use the `Text` property of the cell like this:

```
var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");
ws.Cells["A:A"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-MMM-dd";
ws.Cells["A1"].Value = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(ws.Cells["A1"].Text); // "2022-May-26"
```

Comment: Hi @Ernie.  Thanks for this, but I have 136 columns in my csv, so I would have to write a method that dealt with all of them individually.  Of course, this is possible, but I don't think I am ready to go to those lengths yet!

Comment: @SkinnyPete63  Could you just do it in a regular `for-loop` when you are exporting it?  Maybe post more about what exactly you are trying to do.  I am sure there is a way to automate it somehow.